Using Jfrog artifactory as cache packet repo
I'm trying to configure cargo to fetch packets from crates.io through jfrog artifactory remote.
By using the jfrog cli command:
jf atc
I'm able to get an access token.
However when trying to do a cargo build I get this response:
Caused by: failed to query replaced source registry crates-io`
Caused by:
token rejected for artifactory-remote
Caused by:
failed to get successful HTTP response from https://jfrog.myCompany/artifactory/api/cargo/crates-remote/index/config.json, got 401
body:
{
"errors" : [ {
"status" : 401,
"message" : "Authentication is required"
} ]
}`
I have tried to find documentation on how to do this, however I can't find anythings that helps me.
I have currently done like this to specify the token:
export CARGO_REGISTRY_TOKEN="Bearer eyJ2ZXIiOiIyIiwidHlwIjo......"
I wonder, should I also provide my user name someplace?
Hope anyone can help me, thank's a lot !
